# Does the category of finite sets and injective functions (i.e., monomorphisms) have all coproducts?

Tags: category-theory

My impression is that it does not have all coproducts because:

If $f:A \rightarrow C$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$ are injective functions with $f(a)=g(b) \in C$ for some $a \in A$ and some $b \in B$, then the unique function $(f,g):A+B \rightarrow C$ is not injective. As injectivity is violated, some coproducts cannot be computed in such a category.

Is this correct?

Comment: That same reasoning would work in the category of all sets, so it seems like there is something wrong with your reasoning. What do you think $A+B$ means?

Comment: Hi - welcome to MSE! I don't really understand Thomas Andrews' comment - it seems to me that your argument doesn't work in $\mathbf{Set}$, because not all morphisms in $\mathbf{Set}$ are monic. I think your idea is good, and it's possible to get a proof from that idea. Can you argue that if $\{1, 2\}$ has a coproduct with itself, then $(\mathrm{id}, \mathrm{id}): \{1, 2\} + \{1, 2\} \to \{1, 2\}$ cannot be monic in this category? (think about the definition of coproduct.. and be careful to argue things are distinct)

Comment: You have only shown that the subcategory is not closed under coproducts of sets. This is not enough. Consider, say, the category of torsion abelian groups. It has products, namely the torsion subgroup of the product of abelian groups. It is not closed under (infinite) products of abelian groups, though. Dualize, you get an example for coproducts.

Answer (score 16):

Your argument, as written, appears to me to assume that the coproduct, if it existed, is just the ordinary disjoint union. But it could be the case that the coproduct exists but is something else; in that case the argument would need to be modified, although I do think it can be salvaged.

Here is an alternative argument which is just based on counting. Let $A, B$ be two finite sets. If the coproduct $A \sqcup B$ existed then by definition it would have to satisfy

$$\text{Hom}(A \sqcup B, X) \cong \text{Hom}(A, X) \times \text{Hom}(B, X)$$

for all finite sets $X$. Write $a = |A|, b = |B|, x = |X|$ for the sizes of these sets. The number of injections between two finite sets is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

$$|\text{Hom}(A, X)| = (x)_a = x(x-1) \dots (x-a+1).$$

It follows that

$$|\text{Hom}(A, X)| \times |\text{Hom}(B, X)| = (x)_a (x)_b$$

which is a polynomial of degree $a + b$ in $x$; this means that $A \sqcup B$ must have size $a + b$, but this would imply $(x)_a (x)_b = (x)_{a+b}$ which is false by an inspection of the roots for any $a, b \ge 1$.

In other words, although the definition of the coproduct asks for a *natural* bijection between $\text{Hom}(A \sqcup B, X)$ and $\text{Hom}(A, X) \times \text{Hom}(B, X)$, a counting argument shows that if $A, B$ are non-empty then there is not even a bijection (for all $X$), natural or otherwise.

Comment: Awesome proof !

Answer (score 9):

The category in question fails to have coproducts. I will show that in particular $\{1\} + \{1\}$ fails to exist.

Take the finite set $\{1\}$ and consider the identity map $\mathrm{id}: \{1\} \rightarrow \{1\}$. This is a monomorphism (in fact an isomorphism),  so by the universal property of the coproduct, we can deduce that if the coproduct $\{1\} + \{1\}$ exists, then we have a monomorphism $f: (\{1\} + \{1\}) \hookrightarrow \{1\}$.

This means that $\{1\} + \{1\}$ has at most one element: if we have elements $x,y : \{1\} \rightarrow (\{1\} + \{1\})$, then $f \circ x = f \circ y$, and since $f$ is a monomorphism, we get $x = y$.

Now consider the two elements (constant maps) $c_1,c_2:\{1\} \hookrightarrow\{1,2\}$. We know that $c_1 \neq c_2$. But by the universal property of the coproduct, if it were to exist, we would have a unique monomorphism $g: (\{1\} + \{1\}) \hookrightarrow \{1,2\}$ so that $c_1,c_2$ factor as $g \circ \iota_1 = c_1$ and $g \circ \iota_2 = c_2$ for respective $\iota_1,\iota_2: \{1\} \rightarrow (\{1\} + \{1\})$. Since $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ are elements of $\{1\} + \{1\}$, we'd then have $\iota_1 = \iota_2$ by the previous observation, and consequently $c_1 = g \circ \iota_1 = g \circ \iota_2 = c_2$, a contradiction.

Therefore, the category of finite sets and monomorphisms fails to have coproducts. The failure of existence of coproducts in categories such as $\mathrm{Set}_{mono}$ and $\mathrm{Grph}_{mono}$ is one possible motivation for introducing "proxy" constructions, such as the [proxy pushouts](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.05372) Bumpus and I used in our categorial treatment of treewidth, and the [lens proxy pullbacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.16553) of (Rosebrugh and) Di Meglio.

Answer (score 3):

No two nonempty finite sets have a coproduct in the category of finite sets and injections.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two nonempty finite sets and $C$ is their coproduct with injections $i:A \to C$ and $j:B \to C$.

Then, one needs to find a finite set $D$ with two injections $f:A \to D$ and $g:B \to D$ such that there is no injection $h:C \to D$ for which $h \circ i=f$ and $h \circ j=g$, which would contradict $C$ being a coproduct.

Without loss of generality, assume that $|A| \le |B|$. Then, there is an injection $A \to B$, and of course, the identity is an injection $B \to B$. If there were an injection $C \to B$, then it would follow that $|C|=|B|$ and hence $j$ is a bijection (as any injection between two finite sets of the same size is a bijection). From this and the fact that $C$ is a coproduct, it would follow that any finite set that has an injection from $B$ would have exactly one injection from $A$. This could only happen if $A$ is empty, but it was assumed to be nonempty, which is a contradiction.

So, there is no injection $C \to B$, which means that the coproduct could not exist.

The above proof works regardless of whether $C$ is the disjoint union (the coproduct in the category of finite sets and all functions, not just injective ones) or not.

Comment: I don't quite follow this argument. Why can you conclude that $j$ is a bijection?

Comment: I think this proof is not correct. It also assumes that A+B is the coproduct in the category of sets. It is the same mistake the OP did.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Because $j$ is an injection between two finite sets of the same size.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg To avoid confusion with the disjoint union, I have denoted the coproduct in the category of finite sets and injections as $C$ instead of $A+B$.

Comment: Ah the proof is much better now. +1

Answer (score 2):

The proof by the OP only shows that the subcategory is not closed under coproducts of sets. This is not enough. A subcategory can have products which are different from the ambient category.

Actually, in our case, we can show that this behaviour doesn't appear.

Let $A,B$ be two finite sets.  Assume that $A,B$ have a coproduct $C$ in the category of finite sets with injections, let $\eta_A : A \to C$, $\eta_B : B \to C$ be the inclusions. We will show that $C$ is the disjoint union of the sets $\mathrm{im}(\eta_A)$ and $\mathrm{im}(\eta_B)$.

Let $A+B$ be the coproduct in the category of all sets and maps (just the disjoint union) with the inclusions $\iota_A : A \to A + B$ and $\iota_B : B \to A + B$. Notice that they are injective. So by the universal property of $C$ there is a morphism $f : C \to A$ with $f \circ \eta_A = \iota_A$ and $f \circ \eta_B = \iota_B$. It follows easily that $\mathrm{im}(\eta_A),\mathrm{im}(\eta_B) \subseteq C$ are disjoint since this is the case for the sets $\mathrm{im}(\iota_A),\mathrm{im}(\iota_B) \subseteq A+B$.

Consider $C' := \mathrm{im}(\eta_A) \cup \mathrm{im}(\eta_B)$. We can corestrict $\eta_A,\eta_B$ to get $\eta'_A : A \to C'$, $\eta'_B : B \to C'$, which are still injective. By the universal property of $C$ there is a morphism $f : C \to C'$ with $f \circ \eta_A = \eta'_A$ and $f \circ \eta_B = \eta'_B$. Let $j : C' \to C$ be the inclusion. Then $j \circ f : C \to C$ is an injective map with $j \circ f \circ \eta_A = j \circ \eta'_A = \eta_A$, likewise for $B$. Hence, the (uniqueness of the) universal property of $(C,\eta_A,\eta_B)$ implies $j \circ f = \mathrm{id}_C$. Therefore, $j$ is surjective, i.e. $C' = C$.

This shows that $(C,\eta_A,\eta_B)$ actually is isomorphic to $(A+B,\iota_A,\iota_B)$. Again: this is *not* the case for all subcategories!

And now we can finish the proof by showing that $(A+B,\iota_A,\iota_B)$ is not a coproduct (when $A,B$ are non-empty), like the OP did.